# Woocommerce Stripe Gateway adding metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm looking to add custom metadata at checkout but I'm not sure where I have to add a hook to make it work.
Here's what I have included in function.php but it hasn't worked:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit' , 'metadata_checkout_fields' );

function metadata_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if ( ! $_POST || ( is_admin() && ! is_ajax() ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['post_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['post_data'], $post_data );
    } else {
        $post_data = $_POST; // fallback for final checkout (non-ajax)
    }

    $eleve_nom = $post_data['eleve_prenom'] . ' ' . $post_data['eleve_nom'];

    $fields['billing']['wc-stripe-new-payment-method'] = array(
        'metadata' => array('eleve_nom' => $eleve_nom)
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Do I have to hook on another function or is there a problem with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear or incomplete. Where and when customer is submitting 'eleve_prenom' and 'eleve_nom'? 
It seems that you want to use submitted data on a checkout page hooked function. You should better save before that data in cart object. Then you could use it easily.

Comment: The two field 'eleve_prenom' and 'eleve_nom' came from the checkout form. They are custom field I've created with WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor.
That why I hook before submitting the form and finalize the transaction.

Comment: You need use action for stripe 
`add_action('wc_stripe_payment_metadata', [$this, 'wc_stripe_payment_metadata'], 10, 3);`